# How to handle error of wrong JSON data in Java Rest Web Service: Jackson JSON Parser Unrecognized token

Tags: java, json, rest, jakarta-ee, jackson

this is my web service in which I am receiving JSON in student object.

```
 @PUT
    @Path("/{stuId}")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response update( @PathParam("stuId") UUID stuUUID , Student updatedStudentInfo) {
            return updateService.update(stuUUID, updatedStudentInfo);
        }
```

and this is the student class:

```
    public class Student{

      private int id;
      private String studentName;
      private String Address;

    @JsonProperty
     public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    @JsonProperty
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @JsonProperty
    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }

       .
       .
       .
       .
  }
```

It is working fine but I am not able to handle when scenario when I test it by sending erroneous JSON data. for example if I do it like this 
 
**curl -v 'https://localhost:9803/school/student/29374-345tr-44' -X PUT -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, /' -H 'My-API-Version: 1' -H 'Authorization: Basic' -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8' --data '{"studentName":"rock","Address":723868764}'**

 it geneartes an error:

```
Unrecognized token '723868764': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
```

Now how can I handle this situation that if some erroneous data comes then it should not send back any error or exception except the one which I want to send. 

**EDIT 1:**

Below we can also see the exception which is being generated by Java code

```
 Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'sdfsdfdsfdsf': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null') at 
[Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@5c6d324d; line: 1, column: 59]
```

Comment: why you getting `true`, false or null , its not a Boolean object

Comment: you can try catching that exception and have your own custom message defined in there:  `catch (JSONException e) { //add custome ex message here e.getMessage() }` Also the unrecognized token is being thrown because you have declared Address as String  and possibly trying to set it as a numerical instead of a  String, enclose it in double quotes and that  might make the error go away!

Comment: @coolgirl yea I am passing number instead of string on purpose and this is my question that if I send some wrong JSON data then how can I tackle it?
second, where can I use this TRY CATCH in this code because this exception is being generated at the signature level of method so compiler doesn't even come inside the method.

Comment: I suppose that try catch handling should be done in your service class.

Comment: yea it is already tackled inside the service methods

Comment: Try adding double quote to address ..,"Address": "723868764"}

Comment: @CarlosLaspina - same as the explanation to `coolgirl`, the purpose of the question is to fix error handling. The OP is well aware that the data is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two solutions available for this: 
**Solution 1:** *ExceptionMapper (jersey)*

```
@Provider
public class ClientExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable>
{
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Throwable ex) 
    {

        return Response
                .status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                .build();
    }
}
```

The important thing here is the anotation

> @provider

I am not sure if it is necessary or not after using annotation to put scan configuration in *web.xml* but for the safe side, lets do it

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>my-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>
         com.myrootpackgae.ws;com.anotherPackage.errorHandling;
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.scanning.recursive</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

your ExceptionMapper class should be in the same package of your Rest Service or under the Package hierarchy.
Last but not least, I used Throwable in my example but you can be specific to any Exception for instance

> JsonParseException 
>   JsonMappingException 
>   UnrecognizedPropertyException etc ...

**Solution 2:** *javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter*

```
 public class MyRestAppResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

        @Override
        public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext)
                throws IOException {

            // Remove StackTrace from all exceptions
            Object entity = responseContext.getEntity();
    if (entity instanceof Throwable) {
                responseContext.setEntity(null);
                responseContext.setStatus(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST.getStatusCode());
 }           
            // TF-246 Prevent caching for privacy reasons
            responseContext.getHeaders().add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
            responseContext.getHeaders().add("Pragma", "no-cache");
            responseContext.getHeaders().add("Expires", "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 CET");

            // TF-752 Enable CORS for WkWebView
            responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        }
    }
```

An event listener for request is also available `RequestEventListener` which provides `onEvent(RequestEvent)` method.

 I preferred to use solution #2